# Haskell, define an infinite list, add data on the fly and sort at the same time. How?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have to define a list in which:

- 1 is a member
- if n is a member, so are 2n+1 and 3n+1

So the list is infinite and must be sorted. When loaded to GHCi, the command:

```
"take 10 theList"
```

will produce:

```
[1,3,4,7,9,10,13,15,19,21]
```

Below are my codes:

```
theList = ([1] ++ concat [[(x*2+1),(x*3+1)]|x<-theList])
```

It seems to work except for that it is not sorted, the same command as above produces:

```
[1,3,4,7,10,9,13,15,22,21]
```

Does anyone have any idea to sort that out?
Thanks

Comment: Your `allInOne` function is precisely [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concat). Haskell has many functions "built-in" which you can search by type signature using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) (it is one of the tools that makes Haskell amazing!), e.g. `allInOne` has type `[[a]] -> [a]` and [the first result](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=\[\[a\]\]+-%3E+\[a\]) is the one you're looking for. :)

Comment: There's a nice natural implementation involving _corecursion_. In a way it resembles the infinite list of Fibonacci numbers: `fibs = 0:1:zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`. How would you extend the list when you already have `theList` of some size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be though of as a infinite binary tree (`A` and `B` are labels for the branches):

```
  1__ B
  |  4___
  |   \  13 ...
A 3_   \
  | \   9 ...
  7  10
  ...
```

Thinking about it this way, we can see that we want to write a function ("`listify`") that converts the "tree" into a sorted list. This is where Haskell is really nice: if we have a function (`merge`) that takes two (infinite) sorted lists and merges them into one sorted list (you should write this function), then `listify`-ing the tree is simply `listify`-ing the two branches, merging them and putting the root at the start, i.e. in the tree above

```
1:merge (listify A) (listify B)
```

Since this is homework I won't say much more, but any branch of the tree is entirely determined by the root node, so the type signature of `listify` can be `Integer -> [Integer]`. And once you have `listify`, then `theList = listify 1`.

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried, but since the lists are not sorted there is no way to merge or sort them. Had it worked I would have only had to put another `sort` function in front of the list definition. The thing is, if I did that, and tried 
    `take 20 theList`
Haskell would crash (which means it didn't turn back to the `Main>` command.

I guess I have to create the list on the fly, and sort it as soon as new element is put into it. The only way I can think of is:

    theList = [x|x<-[1..], satisfy x]
        where satisfy x.....

But I'm stuck in the `satisfy` local definition.

Comment: The lists *are* sorted if you've written `listify` and `merge` correctly (this isn't very helpful, I know). Haskell is probably crashing because you are creating an infinite loop (maybe "`listify n`" appears on the right-hand side of the definition of `listify n`? Or similar in `merge`?).

Comment: The problem with this is that duplicates are only dealt with at the merge step, not during generation, which, over time, causes lots of unnecessary work. It does create a very concise, declarative definition though.

Comment: @dan_waterworth it's not that much extra work, though: since the merge is _part_ of the recursive generation, duplicates are pretty much filtered as soon as possible. Sure there are more effective ways, but unless you want really a lot of numbers it should be ok. I get about 5000000 in a minute even in ghci!

Comment: @leftaroundabout, the number of duplicates rises exponentially. It may not particularly matter in this case, but as this is a homework question, it's worth pointing it out.

Comment: @dan_waterworth really? I haven't done the math, but if it were exponential it couldn't possibly succeed calculating millions of numbers in _any_ reasonable time, could it?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, The reason I said it was exponential was that I imagined that the duplicate trees would themselves contain duplicates, but weirdly, this doesn't seem to be the case. The measured duplicate overhead is `O(n)`.

Comment: @dan_waterworth, It is exponential, isn't it? If you have a single number appearing twice, you have two trees (rooted at each occurrence of that number) of O(2^n) identical elements.

Comment: Ah, I believe the reason is this: the higher the numbers, the sparser they appear. There simply aren't so many duplicate numbers even in the unreduced tree. Example, with no duplicate removal: `Prelude> take 30 . drop 400 $ listify 1`
`[2146,2175,2187,2188,2191,2191,2199,2200,2203,2205,2206,2227,2239,2247,2251,2253,2254,2271,2271,2275,2275,2277,2277,2278,2278,2287,2287,2289,2289,2290]`

Comment: @dan_waterworth, @leftaraoundabout, I think we are using different a `n` in our count of duplicates vs our count of tree size: for the count of duplicates we are using `take n` and then counting them, whereas for the tree size `n` refers to the layer (so `2^n` nodes). So the number of duplicates is `O(k)` if `k` is the number of nodes, but the number of nodes is `O(2^n)` if `n` is the layer of the tree, so the number of duplicates is also `O(2^n)`.

Comment: At last I did it, I don't know if my idea is the same to your hints but the code seems surprisingly simple:

aList = [1] ++ merge [2*x+1|x<-aList] [3*x+1|x<-aList]

And yeah, the merge function is the core to solve this problem, everything I did wrong was just instead of creating two list, I added 2n+1 and 3n+1 to the list simultaneously, that's why I couldn't sort it

Answer (score 4):

Another way of seeing this is as a filtered list of integers. The number n is part of the sequence if n = 1 (mod 2) and (n-1)/2 is a part of the sequence, or if n = 1 (mod 3) and (n-1)/3 is a part of the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it won't work with integer numbers, as (6 - 1) `mod` 3 = 1, but 6 shouldn't be in the list as you can see in my question. There is a big rounding problem in here.

Comment: @crazyfffan, I think this does work: 6 /= 1 (mod 3), so it's not even considered by the division. (`mod` and `div` are different functions)